# Scilab syntax error: unexpected endfunction, expecting end

Tags: scilab

I'm new to scilab and writing a simple function throws a syntax error which isn't helping me at all.

```
syntax error: unexpected endfunction, expecting end
```

Someone can point me the error, everything seems fine to me.

I'm saving with .sci extension.

```
function y = bin2SignDec(bin)
    // Determines the signal of the binary number
    if part(bin, 1:1) == '0' then
        signal = 1;
    else
        signal = -1;

    // remove the signal bit from the string
    uBin = part(bin, 2:length(bin));

    // find the position of the decimal point and split the value in two variables
    pointIndex = strindex(uBin, '.');
    integerStr  = part(uBin, 1:(pointIndex-1));
    fractionStr = part(uBin, (pointIndex+1):length(uBin));

    // convert integer part to decimal
    integer = bin2dec(integerStr);

    // convert fraction part to integer
    fraction = 0;
    for i = 1:length(fractionStr)
        fraction = fraction + strtod(part(fractionStr, i:i)) * 2^(-i);
    end

    // return
    y = integer + fraction;

endfunction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `end` is missing after the `if then else` construct.